# how to keep worker thread alive in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, backgroundworker

## Issue

How can I keep the worker.1 thread from crashing on heroku ?

## What I want

I would like a VERY simple worker thread / application that waits around for a request from the end point... when the end point is hit, the end point creates a worker, calls into the worker thread (or whatever mechanism is required) and the worker runs on the background thread.

I don't want to use Redis, Bull and Throng or for that matter any other third party stuff - unless the component is simple to use and easy to maintain.

### Background information about project

The application is a VERY basic NodeJS app.

Client : the client is not even run... but package.json mentions it... so I did too.

Server : NodeJS, has one end point, has a background worker

## Project hierarchy

[image: Project Hierarchy]

## Server side files

I am only showing server side files, as like I said, the client doesn't run in this problem.

### Procfile

```js
worker : node worker.js
```

### Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "workerthreadtest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Worker thread test server",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "Me :-)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.0",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "threads": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

### server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

var api = '/api';
const test = require('./routes/api/endpoint');
app.use( api + '/test', test);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
  }

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(` `);
  console.log(`server info: `);
  console.log(`  port ${port}`);
  console.log(` `);
  console.log(`server ready`);
});
```

### worker.js

```js
const {Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads');

  if (isMainThread) {
    console.log('MAIN THREAD : worker');

    process
    .on('SIGTERM', () => { console.log("PROCESS SIGTERM"); })
    .on('SIGINT', () => { console.log("PROCESS SIGINT");   })
    .on('uncaughtException', () => { console.log("PROCESS uncaught exception");});

    module.exports = function parseJSAsync(data) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('parseJSAsync : creating worker with this data',data);
        const worker = new Worker(__filename, { workerData: data });
        worker.on('message', (msg) =>{console.log('parseJSAsync : resolving',msg); resolve});
        worker.on('error', (err) => {console.log('parseJSAsync : err',JSON.stringify(err)); reject;});
        worker.on('exit', (code) => {
            if (code !== 0)
            reject(new Error(`parseJSAsync stopped with exit code ${code}`));
        });
      });
    };
  } else {
    console.log('WORKER THREAD : with data:', workerData);

    parentPort.postMessage('done');
  }
```

### endpoint.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const parseJSAsync = require('../../worker');

router.post('/add', (req,res) => {
    console.log('in end point calling worker');
    parseJSAsync('foo');
    console.log('in end point returning status');
    res.json({status:'ok'});
});
module.exports = router;
```

### worker.1 crashes during deployment

When I deploy the worker.1 thread crashes

```js
2020-05-06T17:33:41.468191+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-06T17:33:43.280082+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I can see the main thread starting up and exposing the parseJSAsync function

```js
2020-05-06T19:07:23.224874+00:00 app[web.1]: MAIN THREAD : worker
```

### Here is the entire deploy log

Here is the entire output from deployment

```js
2020-05-06T17:33:31.681013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-05-06T17:33:31.697047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-05-06T17:33:31.728905+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-06T17:33:31.488379+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 3759e04c by user michael
2020-05-06T17:33:31.488379+00:00 app[api]: Release v30 created by user michael
2020-05-06T17:33:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-06T17:33:41.468191+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-06T17:33:43.280082+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-05-06T17:33:44.358593+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-06T17:33:44.358681+00:00 app[web.1]: > workerthreadtest@0.1.0 start /app
2020-05-06T17:33:44.358720+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-05-06T17:33:44.358728+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-06T17:33:44.532443+00:00 app[web.1]: MAIN THREAD : worker
2020-05-06T17:33:44.539430+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-06T17:33:44.539527+00:00 app[web.1]: server info:
2020-05-06T17:33:44.539613+00:00 app[web.1]: port 50891
2020-05-06T17:33:44.539700+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-06T17:33:44.539770+00:00 app[web.1]: server ready
2020-05-06T17:33:44.832507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

## Invoke the Worker from the End Point

When I actually invoke the worker... it does not run on the worker thread, as I expect, but instead it runs on app[web.1]

```js
2020-05-06T17:48:02.576142+00:00 app[web.1]: WORKER THREAD : with data: foo
```

### entire output from invoking the worker from the end point

```js
2020-05-06T17:48:02.495128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/test/add" host=workerthreadtest.herokuapp.com request_id=19ca6672-36e6-4e01-a561-9067538850d6 fwd="66.7.228.252" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=66ms status=200
bytes=221 protocol=https
2020-05-06T17:48:02.448582+00:00 app[web.1]: in end point calling worker
2020-05-06T17:48:02.449954+00:00 app[web.1]: parseJSAsync : creating worker with this data foo
2020-05-06T17:48:02.460729+00:00 app[web.1]: in end point returning status
2020-05-06T17:48:02.576142+00:00 app[web.1]: WORKER THREAD : with data: foo
2020-05-06T17:48:02.576652+00:00 app[web.1]: parseJSAsync : resolving done
2020-05-06T17:52:04.905374+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-06T17:52:15.523852+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-06T17:52:16.945097+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: I can't immediately speak to why worker.1 is crashing, but the reason the worker thread is run on web.1 when you call the endpoint is because that is where the server is listening and when the code executes it runs using the worker file in that process.

Comment: @mr_greb - how do I setup a call / file / process (whatever it takes) to transfer that call into the background thread ? In other words, how can I keep the worker thread alive and do processing on it ?

Comment: You could start a child process https://medium.com/@NorbertdeLangen/communicating-between-nodejs-processes-4e68be42b917 unless you require that they run in separate dyno's on heroku.

Comment: @mr_greb - I'd like them to have their own dyno... so they are completely free of the main thread and can be scaled independently (like this: heroku ps:scale web=1 worker=5 )

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to directly talk between two dynos, you could do something like an external queue that the server pushes data onto and the background workers pull from. Or the workers could have their own internal endpoint that the server hits with the data.